# Transform $f''_{xy}$ into $u$ and $v$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Transform $f''_{xy}$ into $u$ and $v$. See paper below.

I miss out on one term, I suspect that I forgot the product rule somwhere, but I cannot tell where. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{du} \frac{du}{dx} + \frac{df}{dv} \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{df}{du} + \frac{df}{dv} y.
$$
Second
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2f}{dx dy} = \frac{d}{dy}\frac{df}{dx} &=
\frac{d^2f}{du^2} \frac{du}{dy} + \frac{d^2f}{du dv} \frac{dv}{dy} + 
\frac{d^2f}{du dv} \frac{du}{dy} y + \frac{d^2f}{dv^2} \frac{dv}{dy} y + \frac{df}{dv} \\&= 
\frac{d^2f}{du^2} + \frac{d^2f}{du dv} x + 
\frac{d^2f}{du dv} y + \frac{d^2f}{dv^2} x y + \frac{df}{dv} \\&=
\frac{d^2f}{du^2} + \frac{d^2f}{du dv} u + \frac{d^2f}{dv^2} v + \frac{df}{dv} .
\end{align}